# Difference betweeen hidden links and blogroll link kept hidden?

Tags: wordpress, links, blogroll

I was reading about [hidden links](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/hidden-links/). I had a question in mind that when I use WordPress's blogroll option, it asks me to either show the link or keep it hidden. How is it different than the hidden link tactic?
Please help out. Thanks

[image]

Comment: I have wondered about this too, for a long time! Partly because of SEO penalty like Matt Cutts said (though he also said it was a concern of the Federal Trade Commission, and the article was dated Aug 2007), but also, what is the purpose of having these private i.e. `hidden` links like this on the blogroll? Good question! I'm happy you thought of asking it!

Comment: The purpose is the same as setting a post to draft status. Not showing something (sometimes just temporarily) is not the same as needing to *delete* it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by hidden you mean not displayed then there's no issue there at all. The links aren't made invisible., they're not there at all. That's perfectly fine. Content that isn't there can't hurt you.

Comment: Sorry if I had not been clear before but I meant to keep the link private in Wordpress. I have added the image for clearifying. Thanks

Comment: If the link is private, it isn't output to the site *at all*. What Cutts was talking about was outputting the link and then making it less apparent, such that spiders etc will still crawl them.